# How can I reduce the width of a form check box?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, checkbox

I have a form, ending with an "I agree to these terms and conditions line" with a checkbox.

The code that I have for the checkbox is currently:

Although all is functioning well, the width of the checkbox element is too much. This causes a very wide space between the "I agree..." statement, and the actual checkbox. Any tips on how I can left align the checkbox, or reduce the width of the checkbox's element.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGPrX.png)

Comment: Please use https://jsfiddle.net/ to share your code for this page.

Answer (score 0):

Standard checkboxes in Rails could be changed with CSS in the following way:

```
input[type="checkbox"]
  width: 10px //or however wide you desire
  height: 10px
```

Although you should be detailed with your selector in case your checkbox is wrapped in some div with an ID, in which case the above will look slightly different:

```
#div input[type="checkbox"]
  width: 10px //or however wide you desire
  height: 10px
```